# How to make a specific search field uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using an 'Individual column searching' as specified in [DataTables' documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

What I want to accomplished is to make the second search field (located below the column) value UPPERCASE as the user types a date.

Here's my .js file:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
             /*More Code*/
             columnDefs: [
                          { targets: 0, visible: false },
                          { targets: 1, render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'D-MMM-YY' ) }
    ],
             columns: [
                       { /* DATA */},
                       { data: "logEntryTime" },
                       { /* DATA */},
                       { /* DATA */},
                       { /* DATA */},
                       { /* DATA */},
             ]
             /*More Code*/
        });

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                 }
            } );
       } );
    } );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say you type '12-jun' in the second search field, what I want is to transform that string into '12-JUN'. And then use it to search as intended by the API.

Comment: You might want to use *case-insensitive* search instead

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to use css.

`text-transform: uppercase;`

However, that only changes the appearance of the text. If you need to change the value of the text, then you would use some JS.

`input.value.toUpperCase()`